# Custom Akka Streams GraphStage with Futures, like `mapAsync`

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have an akka-streams application that performs some IO side-effect wrapped in a `Future` midway through processing. Normally I would make this call via `mapAsync`, but i need to cache information for the previous element after a successful call, i.e. **the IO call is generated from the result of the previous call.**

The example `Map` implementation provided on Akka website is quite simple, but the implementation of `mapAsync` is more complex. Is there any boilerplate or subclass that can be used to implement a GraphStage with async operations? My inclination is that `onPush` and `onPull` will need to check if the "held" future is completed, before yielding its result and replacing it.

On a side note, I could also send this to an actor with the `ask` pattern. But I'm unsure if that actor will have proper back-pressure with something like a bounded mailbox.

Comment: If the IO call is "generated from the result of the previous call" then how should IO be done with the very 1st element in the Stream, since there was no previous call???